# MS MVC (razor) Access view data for serializartion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, serialization, razor

I have a view within a MS MVC [razor] project where I want to submit view data back to a controller via a JSON post operation. I have looked around and I cannot find how to retrieve and package the view data  for submission back to the controller. I was under the assumption that the JSON serialize operation would package the data when called but this does not seem to be happening. For example:

MVC View ------------------------------

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
   {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <center>
        <fieldset  id="UserCreateFieldset">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="button" name="CreateButton" value="Create"  onclick="CreateUser()"   />
            </p>                                    
        </fieldset>
    </center>
   }

   <script>

    function CreateUser()
    {
        var infoForm = $("#UserCreateFieldset");
        var entries = infoForm.serializer.Serialize(Model);

        $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: '@Url.Action("CreateUser", "User")',
                        data: entries,
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data)
                        {
                            $.event.trigger({
                                type: "CreateUserCompleted",
                                NewUserID: 1,
                            });
                        }
                    });               
    }
   </script>
```

---

Just to note; when the controller is called via the post it receives back the model -- but it contains the original values used to load the view.

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [.serialize()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize) method from jquery:

```
function CreateUser()
{
    var data = $('form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateUser", "User")',
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data)
        {
            $.event.trigger({
                type: "CreateUserCompleted",
                NewUserID: 1,
            });
        }
    });               
}
```

You can instead of using `Html.BeginForm` use [`Ajax.BeginForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to not mess with the internals if you are doing the same thing as a the `Html.BeginForm` without anything special. you could change your code to:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController",
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST"
            }))
{
    // Same form
}
```

It even has [OnSuccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onsuccess%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method which can be used in the `AjaxOptions` declaration:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController",
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                OnSuccess = "TriggerEvent"
            }))
{
    // Same form
}
```

And you set a function in the javascript to be called on success:

```
function TriggerEvent() {
    $.event.trigger({
        type: "CreateUserCompleted",
        NewUserID: 1,
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input. The suggestion did not work.  Maybe I should clarify what I'm trying to do. In default operation of a [razor] MVC view when a submit operation is performed (initiated by a input control) the controller is called with the updated values in the view.

What I am trying to do is perform the same operation within a JS script function. I do not know how the current view data is retrieved and packaged [as a json object] for the call to the controller. The example I gave above is incorrect and is a typo. I realize/believe the Model object used would be related to the init Model.

Comment: Yeah I thought you were trying to pass the Model to javascript which that is the correct way to do it. On your actual problem you are trying to get the complete form and post it via ajax? Let me update the answer then.

Comment: Ok; using the Ajax.BeginForm does work. But I'm getting a strange result after the controller action is called. I'm receiving a do you want to open or save CreateUserXXX.json message. I'm not sure why but I am returning a result from the action (which I will require for later). Also the success function is not being called.

Comment: As a second note: I attempted to use the serialize operation and I am not getting the data from the form. The way you show the serialize operation working is using the form object. This is not returning anything. I also used this operation on the fieldset surrounding the data operations and it didn't work either. What is the proper way for this to work.

Also note: I did return null from the action and did not get anything but the app did go to another view. I want the action operation top be canceled, i.e. the app to stay on the same view.

Comment: Thanks for the info - you gave me info to research and I was able to get things working the way I wanted. I was expecting to find more information than I did on this topic or maybe my search criteria was not exact enough.

Comment: I had added the documentation for the `.serialize()` method in which it states that is the correct way of calling it. For the action not to redirect you have to stop the form from actually submitting adding a `return false;` at the end of the `CreateUser()` method or calling [`.preventDefault();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) on the event that the `CreateUser()` method can receive if you change the method to `function CreateUser(event)`.

Comment: The problem you are having from the `Ajax.BeginForm` returning something to download is that your `CreateUser` action from your `User` controller is probably an `ActionResult` which returns a view, this you have to change it to a `JsonResult` and return something like `return Json("success")` or whatever you want it to return to the `TriggerEvent` method which I think you can accept a variable called `data` like `function TriggerEvent(data)` and work with it.